# Where is all the data stored for my web app?

Tags: heroku, server-side

This is probably a very basic question, but I don't know how to phrase it to google the answer.

I'm learning how to use web dev tools like Flask and Heroku. I made a basic web app where you can save some data to a username using a javascript dictionary (not very secure) and HTTP PUT, and load it later using HTTP GET. Using Flask, I route it so that you can view the json at www.mysite.com/username

My question is: Where is all this data stored? How can I get a list of all the users with their data. Every time, I push to Heroku, all the data gets cleared. How do you push without resetting all this stuff I HTTP PUT?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku file systems are ephemeral, meaning they are essentially cleared, or reset, any time you push. Your web application should save its data to a database (Heroku offers Postgres databases for use with web apps).